# python seleniumでjavascriptを無効にする

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

以下のようにwebdriverでFirefox起動時にjavascriptが無効になるように設定しているのですが、設定が反映しません。

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Firefoxで `about:config` から値を確認してみると `javascript.enabled` の項目が `true` になっています。
Firefoxの `about:config` の画面で `javascript.enabled` をダブルクリックすると `false` にはできるのですが、試験の度に手動で`false`に切り替えるというわけにもいかず

python側で `javascript.enabled` の値を指定できる方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

バージョンは以下の通りです。
python 3.5.1
selenium 3.3.3
Firefox 51.0.1 (32 ビット)
Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

検証OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
[image: スクリーンショット]

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.get('about:config')
sleep (3)
browser.find_element_by_id('warningButton').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('about-config-search').send_keys('javascript.enabled')
sleep (3)
browser.find_element_by_class_name('button-toggle').click()
```